# Creating and Returning a List of Employees in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, sample

Good evening all. I'm just trying to create a class with a method that allows you to create a list of users, their ages, and their departments (although I haven't coded the department part yet!). I want to be able to return the list of employees SORTED by age. I haven't coded Java in a long while, and I'm a little rusty. Most of my time has been spent in Perl and C++ lately, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, guys!

Here's my (broken) code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
public class Department{

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("How many employees?\n");
    int noOfEmployees = in.nextInt();
    String[][] employeeInformation;
    employeeInformation = new String[noOfEmployees][3];



    for (int row = 0; row < employeeInformation.length; row++){
        System.out.print("Enter employee name: ");
        try {
            employeeInformation[0][row] = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                }
        System.out.print("Enter employee age: ");
        try {
            employeeInformation[1][row] = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
     Arrays.sort(employeeInformation, new Comparator<String[]>() { 
           public int compare(String[] entry1, String[] entry2){
            String name = entry1[0];
            String age = entry2[0];
            return name.compareTo(age);
           }
            });
     for(int i=0;i<employeeInformation.length;i++){
         System.out.println(employeeInformation[i][i]);
     }
    }   
}
```

Comment: so what is broken?  Help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry! 
Here's my current output after sort:

How many employees?

2
Enter employee name: chris
Enter employee age: 22
Enter employee name: ben
Enter employee age: 21
22
ben

Comment: Be clear in your problem.  From your code, I doubt if you have ever actually code in Java, or even code seriously:  `return name.compareTo(age);` this problem is so obvious isn't it?  Learn to write a proper class, and write small programs to learn to 1. read data from stdin, and 2. do sorting.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OK I have some thing for you. I took your class and modified it to make work and make little better. You may still want to make more error checking and other optimizations as you see fit. This is just a working sample.

**Code explanation:**
I have created a inner class called employee. But feel free to tear that out into a separate class. I just did for convenience sake to post a sample. I hope it helps you.I have tested and it works.

```
package com.vkg;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Department {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Department department = new Department();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many employees?\n");
        int noOfEmployees = in.nextInt();
        Employee[] employees = new Employee[noOfEmployees];

        for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            Employee employee = department.new Employee();
            System.out.print("Enter employee name: ");
            String employeeName = in.next();
            employee.setName(employeeName);

            System.out.print("Enter employee age: ");
            int age = in.nextInt();
            employee.setAge(age);

            employees[i] = employee;
        }
        Arrays.sort(employees);

        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            System.out.println(employee.getName() + "'s age = " + employee.getAge());
        }
    }

    public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
        private String name;
        private int age;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Employee o) {
            if(this == o || this.age == o.age) {
                return 0;
            } else if (this.age < o.age) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not the downvoter, but this does not fix **his** code

Comment: What is still broke? Have tried to run this? I tested the output and it works. Can the DOWNVOTER please explain the reason for downvoting? Just curious?

Comment: I think the idea is to _help_ the poster with his code, not do his work for him.

Comment: Is that the reason somebody downvoted me? But keep in mind different users need different level of help based on their expertise. And I think idea is to help everyone here isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted, but thanks for the guidance. I actually have been coding for a long while now, but I'm trying to pick up where I left off on Java. The code I posted in the OP was what I had come up with over digging through some old code and textbooks. Thanks again, I'll work with this and come up with something shiny!

I should also add, the absolute joke of a 2D array I posted was the result of me screwing with things, not an actual completed code at all. I should have been more clear that I just needed guidance.

Comment: If you like what I posted please accept it as a answer. I was honestly trying to help.

Comment: I got distracted trying to upvote, but I don't have enough rep yet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

using your code

```
  employeeInformation[0][row] = br.readLine();
  employeeInformation[1][row] = br.readLine();
```

should be

```
  employeeInformation[row][0] = br.readLine();
  employeeInformation[row][1] = br.readLine();
```

and why are you comparing age with name in your sort

```
return name.compareTo(age);  // this does not make sense.
```

Sorry to be rough, but try using a debugger or print statements